# In if statements, if I assign a value to a variable, do I have to do it again in the else statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

Let's say I have this code

```
if ((p = malloc(int)) == null) { do something }

else { do something else with p }
```

I know the syntax may be incorrect, but if, lets say, the condition inside the if statement is not true and is not equal to null and we move on to the else statement, will `p` still be assigned `malloc(int)` if I try to work with `p` in the else statement? Or do I have to assign `malloc(int)` to `p` in the else statement again?

Comment: "will p still be assigned malloc " - it isn't being assigned the result of `malloc` *now* regardless. The syntax is only incorrect if you *didn't* want to leak memory. Your assignment should be enclosed in parens. Fix that and the `else` block should have a non-null `p` that caused failure in the `if` test.

Comment: You can test the hypothesis with simple assignments, rather than risking UB by messing around with a pointer that *might* point to valid memory. And no, you don't have to repeat the assignment in the `else` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is the following

```
if ((p = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{
    // Here p is equal to NULL
    // skip the else statement
} else {
    // Jump here if the allocation was successful and p is not equal to NULL
}
```

Thus if you will use the parentheses correctly then at first the assignment

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int))
```

is evaluated before checking the condition.

Comment: I have a quick follow up question. Lets say I have the following struct in c

    struct thing{
     int A;
     int B;
    };

If I decide to use malloc to allocate space for it and I assign the space to int *p. Does the space allocated contain a struct thing where I can access its parameters A and B using p->A or p->B? Or is it simply just a memory space where I store a struct?

Comment: @JohnGringus You can define an object of the structure either like struct thing t; and access its data members like t.A and t.B. Or you can allocate an object dynamically like struct thing *t = malloc( sizeof( struct thing ) ); and access its data members like t->A and t->B.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular example, `p` isn't getting assigned what you think it is.  The equality operator `==` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.

So this:

```
(p = malloc(int) == null)
```

Is the same as:

```
(p = (malloc(int) == null))
```

Which means `p` gets assigned the result of the boolean expression.

What you want is:

```
((p = malloc(int)) == null)
```

This assigns the result of `malloc` to `p`, then compares that value against `NULL`.  Whether the condition is true or not, the assignment has already been done.  So `p` either contains `NULL` or a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.